# Enum is evaluated to unexpected values

Tags: c++, gcc, enums

I've got the following enum definition:

```
enum ReadMode {
    File = 0,
    MemMappedFile = 1,
    RAM = 2,
    VRAM = 3,
    DMA = 4
};
```

And now I'm experiencing the issue that `RAM` is evaluated to 1 and `DMA` is evaluated to 2.
I'm using gcc, so maybe there is an issue there?

I don't know what additional information might be useful, maybe the assigning of the Values:

```
struct ConfigEntry {
    AssetRepoConfigBase::ReadMode readMode;

    void Init(AssetRepoConfigBase::ReadMode _readMode) {
        readMode = _readMode;
    }
};
```

And somehwere later:

```
if (m_ConfigEntries != 0) {
    m_ConfigEntries[0].Init(DMA);
    m_assetRepoConfigEntries[1].Init(RAM);
}
```

The problem here is: I'm using 2 libraries (both compiled using the same compiler), where 1 library contains the configuration and the other one reads the Data. Now one library is accessing this data and there I get problems because in one library these values are evaluated as expected.

PS: actually this structure contains additional data which is set by the init method, I just stripped it down to simplify. This additional data is as expected, so I don't think it's an initialisatio issue.

PPS: The config library (where this problem occurs) does only use `DMA` and `RAM` from the enum, maybe some kind of optimization issue (in the other lib all enumerations are used).

Comment: are you 100% sure that both libraries use the same header, where the enum is defined ?

Comment: I'd also suspect the libraries might have been compiled with different versions of the `enum` definition.

Comment: I didn't use the header from the same location and they were different. I double checked the enum definition which was ok, but the actual struct definition was slightly different, so there was the problem.